# How do I download a file from a variable URL via shell?

Tags: shell, curl, wget

I have an XML file I want to download via Shell, the URL is

```
http://www.gametracker.com/datafeeds/?server_info&GAMESERVERID=2814889
```

Anyway, I have an issue that whenever I try to download it it ignores the variable or something and instead gives me this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <result>ERROR</result>
    <resultstring>Invalid%20request</resultstring>
</data>
```

What can I do to download the file properly?

Comment: You've got special chars in the string, so you need to quote it. `wget "url"`

Comment: A better question would include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command to download the xml into a file. Hopefully you missed the quotes around the url and hence it broke around the `&` character.

```
curl "http://www.gametracker.com/datafeeds/?server_info&GAMESERVERID=2814889" -o output.xml
```

If you want to use wget:

```
wget "http://www.gametracker.com/datafeeds/?server_info&GAMESERVERID=2814889" -O output.xml
```

Comment: thank you!! this was very succinct, clear, and helpful